# Display different message for different vee-validate regex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vee-validate

I'm using 2 regex in my page, **1st field** using `regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+$/` **2nd field** using `regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$/`, each should display different message.

```
/* First field */
regex: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+$/
errorMessage: "Only alpha, number, underscore, dash and whitespace are allowed"

/* Second field */
regex: /^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$/
errorMessage: "Only alpha, number, and dot are allowed"
```

The code I Know:

```
<ValidationProvider v-slot="{ errors }" name="Second" :rules="{ regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+$/ }">
 <v-text-field
  v-model="first"
  label="First"
  :error-messages="errors"
  ></v-text-field>
</ValidationProvider>

<ValidationProvider v-slot="{ errors }" name="Second" :rules="{ regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$/ }">
 <v-text-field
  v-model="second"
  label="Second"
  :error-messages="errors"
  ></v-text-field>
</ValidationProvider>

<script>
import { regex } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules'
import { extend, ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider} from 'vee-validate'

extend('regex', {
  ...regex,
  message: '{_field_} pattern is wrong yo!',
})
</script>
```

This will show the same message for every `regex` in the form. How can I display different error message for each `regex`?

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this problem would be to make new validators with `extend` and putting there custom error messages, e.g.

```js
extend('custom_validator_1', 
  value => {
    const re = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+$");
    if (re.test(String(value))) {
        return true;
    }
    return 'Only alpha, number, underscore, dash and whitespace are allowed';
});

extend('custom_validator_2', 
  value => {
    const re = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$");
    if (re.test(String(value))) {
        return true;
    }
    return 'Only alpha, number, and dot are allowed';
});
```

And you put in your rules `custom_validator_1` and `custom_validator_1`, respectively.